# C++ Is it possible to simplify this nested loop pattern using reference to a variable?

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference, nested-loops

Problem: I am trying to find a less verbose way to achieve the following code block. The code must create a decreasing pattern of stars using nested loops, and must pass a reference to a function. This is as concise as I've managed so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printStars(int &);

int main( ) {
    int maxNum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> maxNum;

    for (int row = maxNum; row > 0; row--) {
        printStars(row);
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printStars(int &num) {
    for(int col = num; col > 0; col--)
        cout << "*";
}
```

The above works, but it seems like there should be a much more efficient way to do this using references and functions. Any ideas?

This was given to my daughter's class as a quiz exercise. I attempted to leave the original question out, but have decided to post it for reference. It is not worded well.

> Create a pass by reference function call void showPattern(int &) with
>   one parameter. Make the function call in main(). Accept input into int
>   main() of an integer value called highNumber. The high number of the
>   pattern is based on the cin >> input of the user via the function
>   (don't worry about validation). maxNum as a parameter in Main to the
>   function. In function definition, using nested loops display the
>   following pattern:

```
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Why do you think a reference is more efficient? And why do you feel like you must use one?

Comment: It was a quiz question in my daughter's programming class and I'm helping her understand how reference variables work. The question requires that maxNum be passed to a function using a reference variable.

Comment: *My problem is that I need this same result by passing a reference variable to printStars.* Whose requirement is this? Your own? Your teacher's?

Comment: Technical note: There is no such thing as a reference variable. A reference is an alias of a variable, not a variable unto itself.

Comment: Thanks, user4581301. Corrected those in the original question.

Comment: In this specific example there seems to be no gain from passing by reference, so I'm not really understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: I can see an assignment requiring recursion, but references does seem odd. I don't think you can do too much better than what you currently have.

Comment: @LabGecko you are not currently *pass the maxNum to a function*, you pass the *row*

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to get rid of some of the code.
Using `std::string`s constructor to create the right amount of stars thus removing a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printStars(int &);

int main( ) {
    int maxNum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> maxNum;

    printStars(maxNum);
}

void printStars(int &num) {
    while (num)
        cout << std::string(num--, '*') << endl;
}
```

There is still no sense in passing by reference here, but I included it since you stated that was a requirement.

Comment: Nice workaround! The instructor required nested loops, but I like that trick with std::string.

Answer (score 0):

What I gather from your post and replies is that you are suppose to have only one loop in function `printStars` that outputs *s.

You pass the `maxNum` as a reference to `printStars` then use that variable to print stars. Forgive formatting issues. Sorry I am new here.

Comment: I updated the question based on feedback. It should be much more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass row  variable by reference and set it again in main function from maxNum value like this :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printStars(int &);

int main( ) {
  int maxNum = 0.0;
  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> maxNum;

  for (int row = maxNum; row > 0; row--) {
      printStars(row);
      row = maxNum--;
      cout << endl;
  }
}
void printStars(int &num) {
   while(num > 0){
   cout << "*";
    num--;
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is to use references '&' instead of pointers ' * '. Honestly I'm a slight bit fuzzy on the difference though.

Comment: well you mentioned using pass by reference , this implementation is using reference only, since we are passing row's address to the function

Comment: your example is using pointers. Passing pointers into functions only passes a memory address, and to the variable the pointer points to, you need to de-reference them. Passing a reference means that the variable passed as a parameter does not need to be de-refenced to change it in the previous scope

Comment: i have updated the code , hope it works for you now @LabGecko

Comment: I'd certainly consider that a correct answer if I were a professor. Not sure it's any more concise, but as others have mentioned, I'm not sure it's possible to do this in less.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that does the exact same, but using referenced parameters isn't necessary, your example works exactly the same

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printStars(int &);

int main( ) {
    int maxNum = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> maxNum;

    while(maxNum != 0){
        printStars(maxNum);
    }
}

void printStars(int &num) {
    for(int col = num; col > 0; col--)
        cout << "*";

    num--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create a pass by reference function call void showPattern(int &) with one parameter.

```
void showPattern(int &);
```

> Make the function call in main().
>   Accept input into int main() of an integer value called highNumber.

```
int main(){
    //...
    int highNumber;
    //...
}
```

> The high number of the pattern is based on the cin >> input of the user **via the function** (don't worry about validation).

not sure what it means, but I would guess it means in the function

> - maxNum **as a parameter** in Main to the function.
> - In function definition, **using nested loops** display the following pattern:

I don't know why every other answer don't use nested loop but it is required

```
void showPattern(int & maxNum){
    cin >> maxNum;
    for(int row=maxNum;row>0;--row){
        for(int column=row;column>0;--column){
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

and put it together

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

void showPattern(int &);
int main(){
    int highNumber;
    showPattern(highNumber);
    return highNumber;//just to show that the value changes.
}
void showPattern(int & maxNum){
    cin >> maxNum;
    for(int row=maxNum;row>0;--row){
        for(int column=row;column>0;--column){
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

[example in wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lBzHZ6OxARyC8VUl). you can see it returns 10 and give the required pattern

---

this is the closest answer I can provide, the question itself makes little sense, though.

Comment: I agree that there is too much guesswork in the question presented to the class. Part of the discussion the professor gave is that the nested loops are supposed to leverage the use of the function to accomplish the goal. Given the wording I think the prof would be forced to accept that this is a correct solution.